# Get mouse position on responsive canvas on mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a responsive canvas with and it draw a square on mousemove, however I cannot target the mouse position of the canvas, however it works if the canvas is not responsive. how can I target the position of the mouse? Thank you in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/Paul017/yz028mwe/3/

This is the code.

**HTML:**

```
<h4>Drag the mouse to create a rectangle</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; width:100%}
```

**JS:**
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

```
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.5)";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 1;

var $canvas = $("#canvas");
var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX = $canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY = $canvas.scrollTop();

var isDown = false;

var startX;
var startY;


function handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    // set a flag indicating the drag has begun
    isDown = true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    isDown = false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    isDown = false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        // if we're not dragging, just return
        if (!isDown) {
            return;
        }

        // get the current mouse position
        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var width = mouseX - startX;
        var height = mouseY - startY;

        ctx.strokeRect(startX, startY, width, height);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `selectionStart` or `selectionEnd` property of `target` method.

You can get target every position with:

```
e.target.selectionStart
```

or `e.target.selectionEnd`

In your code:

```
function handleMouseMove(e) {
console.log('target event ', e.target);
console.log('selectionStart', e.target.selectionStart);
console.log('selectionEnd', e.target.selectionEnd)
     e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        // if we're not dragging, just return
        if (!isDown) {
            return;
        }

        // get the current mouse position
        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var width = mouseX - startX;
        var height = mouseY - startY;

        ctx.strokeRect(startX, startY, width, height);

    }
```

If the console log show undefined, try to console log you e.target. You will find the selectionStart and selectionEnd method.

Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: may I know on how would you apply the selection start and selection end?

Comment: the selection start and selection end should be visible (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectionEnd) as a method when you console.log (e.target). Could you write which method you see when you console log (e.target) please?

Comment: thanks for your help. I've already figured it out but not using selectionStart and selectionEnd

Comment: What did you use then? I am curious :)

Comment: this one. https://jsfiddle.net/Paul017/yz028mwe/28/

Answer (score 0):

I have already figured it out by using these mouse positions code to target the x and y location in a responsive canvas

```
 e.offsetX * canvas.width / canvas.clientWidth | 0
 e.offsetY * canvas.width / canvas.clientWidth | 0
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Paul017/yz028mwe/28/